# Return records which have unique data in a field

Tags: mysql, ms-access, select, count, vba

I want to return records from one table which only have one linked record in another table.

For example, 2 tables, tblClients and tblOrders with an OTM relationship linked by tblClients.ID and tblOrders.ClientID(not my situation exactly but easier to explain).  I wish to open frmClients with a filter where the client has only placed one order - ie records where tblorders.ClientID has not been repeated in another record in tblOrders.

By the seems of reading around, a SELECT/COUNT query seems to be the way to go, but I can't seem to get the syntax to work correctly.  Here's what I've got so far:

```
Public Function onlyone()
Dim uWHERE As String
uWHERE = "SELECT tblOrders.Client_ID FROM tblOrders WHERE Count(tblOrders.Client_ID) = 1;"
Debug.Print uWHERE
End Function
```

I am very limited with SQL and not brilliant with VBA (if it isn't apparent from the above!)  If i run this code in an OpenForm, with uWHERE as the WHERE clause, i get a syntax error (I have other, simpler WHERE clauses working fine in other subs).  If I output uWHERE to a msgbox I get the SELECT string as a prompt and the debug.print line does nothing.

I think I'm totally handling this syntax incorrectly or haven't got my head round what the SELECT query is actually pulling, but can't figure out how to resolve it.  I'd appreciate a little guidance =]

Thanks!

EDIT++++++++++++++++

OK, different tack.  tblOrders has an unbound listbox whose rowsource is set from a date of order placed for that Client_ID.  If they only placed one order, there is only one entry so is there a way I can open the form only showing records which have one entry in this listbox?  I've tried

```
Dim uWHERE As String
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmworklog", , , , acFormEdit
With frmworklog
Filter = "forms!frmworklog.searchres.listcount = 1"
FilterOn = True
End With
Msgbox Forms!frmworklog.searchres.ListCount
```

The filter does not work, but the msgbox gives the correct count for the opening record.  uWHERE was a WHERE clause and defined the same as 'Filter' is now - I just forgot to take the declaration out.

Many Thanks =]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

For conditions on aggregation values, use `having`, not `where`:

```
SELECT o.Client_ID
FROM tblOrders o
HAVING Count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - this still throws up a syntax error for me in an OpenForm command.  Should I be using the result differently - with a RecordSet or something?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to my question, but it an acceptable workaround for my purposes so maybe it can be implemented for others too.

I added an extra field 'Orders' to tblOrders which kept a running total of orders attributed to that ClientID using the unbound box 'searchres' which contained a list of dates of each order placed under that ClientID:

```
Private Sub btnsave_Click()

Me.Orders = Me.searchres.ListCount
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
Me.searchres.Requery

End Sub
```

I can then use a simple OpenForm command where Orders = 1.

Job done.